# Call directive from other directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive:

```
elem.ready(() => {
    scope.$apply(() => {
        const func = $parse(attrs.elemReady);
        func(scope);
    });
});
```

On a element I can add this:

```
elem-ready="callThisFunction()"
```

And that will call the `callThisFuncion()` method in the controller. But I would like to load a different directive.

Comment: It is unnecessary to use `elem.ready` in a directive linking function. The $compile never runs before `DOMContentLoaded`.

Answer (score 2):

The code is overly complicated.

> OVERLY COMPLICATED
>
> ```
> elem.ready(() => {
>     scope.$apply(() => {
>         const func = $parse(attrs.elemReady);
>         func(scope);
>     });
> });
> ```

### BETTER

```
scope.$eval(attrs.elemReady);
```

It is unnecessary to use `elem.ready` in a directive linking function. The $compile never runs before `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: Okay, but that was not the question.